# Javascript: onclick event triggers twice

Tags: javascript, onclick

Is there a way to change `onclick` handler inside itself without triggering it twice?

```
class Xfoo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }

  foobar() {
    alert();
    this.onclick = this.foobar;
} }

let x = document.getElementById('xfoo');
x.onclick = function() { this.foobar(); };
```

When `xfoo` element clicked, two alerts appears.

Comment: I don't see this behavior you describe ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2b0kza1/)). There's probably some other code binding `onclick` to `foo` more than once. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @p.s.w.g It happens second time you click.

Comment: @MaheerAli The second time you click, it does trigger twice, but this is not due to the wrapper function. You can fix it by using `foo.onclick` rather than `this.onclick` -- so I think it's due to wonky event binding.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use wrapper function directly assign it `bar`.

```js
let foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.onclick = function bar() {
  alert();
  this.onclick = function(){bar()};
};
```

```html
<button id="foo">foo</button>
```

#### What happens due to wrapper function?

When you set the `onclick` to `function(){bar()}`. you are changing the `this` binding.And it attaches event to `this` as well as `this` which is `window` and afterwords when you click the button due to event bubbling the event is called two times.

You can also `bind` `this` and use arrow function if you want wrapper function.

```js
let foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.onclick = function bar() {
  alert();
  this.onclick = () => bar.bind(this)();
};
```

```html
<button id="foo">foo</button>
```

Comment: Still triggers twice.

Comment: @user11268123 In the snippet it doesnot. Please check it again